# namespace on external content type

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, external-list

I have noticed that when moving BCS lists/external content types from my development computer to our production server, it keeps the namespace of my development computer.

For example, all the external lists that I created natively on our production server have the namespace of "http://intranet.com/site/subsite/etc" but the ones that I imported have a namespace of "http://devcomputer.com/site".

Is this a cause for concern? The lists seem to be functioning correctly and the production server should have no knowledge or access to my development computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of the *namespace* + *BCS name* ensures that the name is unique.  That way you could have multiple BCSs named *Products* each having different DBs as their source and still being acceptable.

I never had any issues, even with bogus namespaces.  I use them to classify my BCS and order them by sites.

Regards.